# Was it common among soldiers to put boot blacking on other soldiers' private parts during WW I?

Tags: history, adolf-hitler, world-war-i

The claim is hidden in a long article about some other ... uhm delicate ... myths surrounding Hitler [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1087380/Did-Hitler-really-ONE-testicle-A-historian-sorts-extraordinary-truth-far-flung-myths-Fuhrer.html):

> according to a former comrade of Hitler's from the trenches, Hans
>   Mend, his comrades used to put boot blacking on the future Fuhrer's
>   penis when he was asleep in the trenches, which Dr Machtan describes
>   as 'evidently a common occurrence' in the German army in the Great
>   War.

Comment: Without actual knowledge of the matter, it seems to me that it is rather unlikely that this wouldn't wake one up.

Comment: @Erik Before or while shinning?